# How to randomly generate (x, y) points following a linear equation?

Tags: r, random

I have a equation y=9x+6. I want to extract 10 random points from this function. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 5):

Generate 10 random x-values, in this example uniformly distributed (function `runif`), and then calculate the corresponding y-values following your equation.

You can control the x-range by setting different `min` and `max` parameters to function `runif`.

```r
x <- runif(10, min = 0, max = 1)
y <- 9*x+6
plot(x,y)
```

[image]